# What is the Mod4+D shortcut key?

Tags: shortcut-keys

In `System/Preferences/KeyboardShortcuts` there is a shortcut key called `Mod4+D` that can be used to minimize windows.  How is `Mod4+D` entered on a keyboard and what is the meaning of the Mod4?

Comment: Super key(win key)?

Comment: Mod4 is the windows key (between ctrl and alt on the left side of space): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key#Use_with_non-Microsoft_operating_systems

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can see what keys are bound to which modifiers using the `xmodmap` tool.  For example:

```
$ xmodmap
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

The `Super_L` and `Super_R` keysyms correspond to the <kbd>Win</kbd> keys on your keyboard.

Comment: Shift_L means left shift key? What does Meta_L and Hyper_L means? and mod5 bindings ?

Comment: They keyboards on some of the UNIX systems around at the time when X was being developed had a lot more modifiers than today's keyboards.  So it is likely that no there are no keys on your keyboard mapped to some of the keysyms listed above.  You are right about the `_L` and `_R` suffixes meaning left and right though.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-cadet_keyboard for an example of one such keyboard.